# Listener not sending last chunk of data to the database in JMeter

Tags: jmeter

Am using an listener with customized code to collect the telemetry data and send it to a time series database [in my case it is influxdb]. To handle the overhead in the JMeter side, am trying to create a batching for pushing these telemetry data to the time series database. Now current script is running smoothly and whenever the batching condition is satisfying then it is pushing the data, but the last chunk of data which is the part of the end of execution is not pushing to the database. I tried to put a `if--else if--else` but it is not working.

```java
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
import org.apache.http.entity.StringEntity;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.apache.http.params.BasicHttpParams;
import org.apache.http.util.EntityUtils;
import org.apache.jmeter.samplers.SampleResult;

try {

    Metrics = new StringBuilder();
    String status = "Failure";
    if (sampleResult.isSuccessful())
    status = "Success";
    if (sampleResult.getSampleLabel().startsWith("/"))
    Metrics.append("Requests")
    else
    Metrics.append("JMeter_Result")
    Metrics.append(",requestName=")
    .append(escapeValue(sampleResult.getSampleLabel()))
    .append(",httpstatuscode=")
    .append(sampleResult.getResponseCode())
    .append(",status=")
    .append(status)
    .append(",ScenarioID=")
    .append('${__groovy(vars.get("uniqueScenario_Id"),)}')
    .append(" responseTime=")
    .append(sampleResult.getTime())
    .append(",responsecode=")
    .append("\"${(sampleResult.getResponseCode())}\"")
    .append(",sentBytes=")
    .append(sampleResult.getSentBytes())
    .append(",receivedBytes=")
    .append(sampleResult.getBytesAsLong())
    .append(",responseMessage=")
    .append("\"${(sampleResult.getResponseMessage())}\"")
    .append(",samplecount=")
    .append(sampleResult.getSampleCount())
    .append(",errorCount=")
    .append(sampleResult.getErrorCount())
    .append(" ")
    .append(sampleResult.getTimeStamp())
    .append("000000");
    def measurementBody =  (ArrayList<String>) props.get("measurementBody");
    if(measurementBody == null)
            measurementBody = []
    measurementBody.add(Metrics);
    def NBody = [];
    if(measurementBody.size() > 6){
            log.info('Current Value :'+measurementBody.size()+' Condition Satisfied Data Pushed to influxDB ');
            props.put("measurementBody",NBody);
            PostMeasurement(measurementBody);
        }
        else if (sampleResult.getSampleLabel().equals("UserIdleTime")) {
            log.info('[Final]: As the idle situation arrived finall data pushed to influxDB');
            PostMeasurement(measurementBody);
        }
        
        else {
            log.info('Current Value :'+measurementBody.size()+' Condition Yet Satisfied Data Not Pushed to influxDB ');
            props.put("measurementBody",measurementBody)
        }
} catch (Exception e) {
    log.error("Error in Grafana Metrics Listener : " + e + "\n "+ e.getStackTrace());
}
//Escape the string values before posting the data
String escapeValue(String val) {
    String responseValueForSpaceRemoval;
    responseValueForSpaceRemoval = removeWhiteSpaces(val);
    val = responseValueForSpaceRemoval.replaceAll(",", "\\\\,")
    .replaceAll(" ", "\\\\")
    .replaceAll("=", "\\\\=")
    .replaceAll("\n", " ")
    .replaceAll("\r", " ")
    .replaceAll("\t", " ")
    .trim();
    return val;
}

//Handled all the sampler which have space between, this function will remove the space between
//[Note]:Space need to be remove as we are posting the data to influxdb & if your result have a space between then it will treat it as column value 
static String removeWhiteSpaces(String input) {
    return input.replaceAll(~/\s/, '')
}

// Method For Post the result to the time series database [influxDB]
public void PostMeasurement(ArrayList<String> Body) {
    def httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient(new BasicHttpParams());
    def httpPost = new HttpPost();
    httpPost.setURI(new URI(vars.get("InfluxDBAPI")));
    String stringBodyForDatabase = "";
    Body.each { stringBodyForDatabase = stringBodyForDatabase + it + "\n" };
    httpPost.setEntity(new StringEntity(stringBodyForDatabase))
    HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httpPost);
    EntityUtils.consumeQuietly(response.getEntity());
}
```

Output from the script:

```yaml
2023-04-01 19:59:12,244 INFO o.a.j.e.StandardJMeterEngine: Running the test!
2023-04-01 19:59:12,244 INFO o.a.j.s.SampleEvent: List of sample_variables: []
2023-04-01 19:59:12,252 INFO o.a.j.g.u.JMeterMenuBar: setRunning(true, *local*)
2023-04-01 19:59:12,318 INFO o.a.j.e.StandardJMeterEngine: Starting ThreadGroup: 1 : 01_Study_Creation
2023-04-01 19:59:12,318 INFO o.a.j.e.StandardJMeterEngine: Starting 1 threads for group 01_Study_Creation.
2023-04-01 19:59:12,318 INFO o.a.j.e.StandardJMeterEngine: Thread will continue on error
2023-04-01 19:59:12,318 INFO o.a.j.t.ThreadGroup: Starting thread group... number=1 threads=1 ramp-up=1 delayedStart=false
2023-04-01 19:59:12,318 INFO o.a.j.t.ThreadGroup: Started thread group number 1
2023-04-01 19:59:12,318 INFO o.a.j.e.StandardJMeterEngine: All thread groups have been started
2023-04-01 19:59:12,320 INFO o.a.j.t.JMeterThread: Thread started: 01_Study_Creation 1-1
2023-04-01 19:59:14,842 INFO o.a.j.v.J.Request Sender to InfluxDB: Current Value :5 Condition Yet Satisfied Data Not Pushed to influxDB 
2023-04-01 19:59:21,485 INFO o.a.j.v.J.Request Sender to InfluxDB: Current Value :6 Condition Yet Satisfied Data Not Pushed to influxDB 
2023-04-01 19:59:22,508 INFO o.a.j.v.J.Request Sender to InfluxDB: Current Value :7 Condition Satisfied Data Pushed to influxDB 
2023-04-01 19:59:23,160 INFO o.a.j.v.J.Request Sender to InfluxDB: Current Value :1 Condition Yet Satisfied Data Not Pushed to influxDB 
2023-04-01 19:59:23,936 INFO o.a.j.v.J.Request Sender to InfluxDB: Current Value :2 Condition Yet Satisfied Data Not Pushed to influxDB 
2023-04-01 19:59:24,533 INFO o.a.j.v.J.Request Sender to InfluxDB: Current Value :3 Condition Yet Satisfied Data Not Pushed to influxDB 
2023-04-01 19:59:24,784 INFO o.a.j.v.J.Request Sender to InfluxDB: Current Value :4 Condition Yet Satisfied Data Not Pushed to influxDB 
2023-04-01 19:59:25,019 INFO o.a.j.v.J.Request Sender to InfluxDB: Current Value :5 Condition Yet Satisfied Data Not Pushed to influxDB 
2023-04-01 19:59:25,352 INFO o.a.j.v.J.Request Sender to InfluxDB: Current Value :6 Condition Yet Satisfied Data Not Pushed to influxDB 
2023-04-01 19:59:25,354 INFO o.a.j.t.JMeterThread: Thread is done: 01_Study_Creation 1-1
2023-04-01 19:59:25,354 INFO o.a.j.t.JMeterThread: Thread finished: 01_Study_Creation 1-1
2023-04-01 19:59:25,355 INFO o.a.j.e.StandardJMeterEngine: Notifying test listeners of end of test
2023-04-01 19:59:25,356 INFO o.a.j.g.u.JMeterMenuBar: setRunning(false, *local*)
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

"Listener not sending last chunk of data to the database in JMeter" because the test ends before there is enough data to send (measurements are < 6)

The options are in:

1. You can try putting `if--else if--else` taking into account Thread Group settings (number of users, number of iterations, test duration, etc.) Current Thread Group instance can be obtained as [`ctx.getThreadGroup()`](https://jmeter.apache.org/api/org/apache/jmeter/testelement/TestStateListener.html#testEnded())
2. You can check the "chunk" size in i.e. [tearDown Thread Group](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#tearDown_Thread_Group) and if it is not empty send it from there
3. Your code doesn't look like a "using an listener with customized code" to me otherwise you would have an implementation of [TestStateListener.testEnded()](https://jmeter.apache.org/api/org/apache/jmeter/testelement/TestStateListener.html#testEnded()) function